# Get more informations in ModelChoiceField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a `ModelChoiceField` in a Django form. The functionality works fine, but when I am looping through all the choices in my template I need more informations about the objects instead of just the value of `Model.__str__()`.

I have tried

```
{% for radio in form.field %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ radio.tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ radio.choice_label }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

but I cannot get more informations from the objects (e.g. `radio.name`, `radio.age`, `radio.country`).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The **str** (**unicode** on Python 2) method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices; to provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it.

And an example from the docs:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With that solution I am still only able to get the choice label. I want the entire object instead. An ugly way to do it could probably to include all the object's fields in the label and split it by a separator in the template